# How can I save multiple Pointclouds inside a vector when filling said vector with a for loop?

Tags: c++, pointers, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

EDIT: I use PCL one in all installer 1.12.0 on Windows 11. Used cmake to build a project with librealsense and pcl. My IDE is Visual Studio 2019

I get multiple point clouds out of multiple depth frames from 2 cameras. I want to use some filters on each point cloud, so I loop through the vector of point clouds with a for loop. Before the first iteration of the loop can finish I get a Debug Assertion Failed: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block) error. This only happens in debug mode but not in release mode.

```
std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr, Eigen::aligned_allocator <pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr >> filtered_clouds1;
std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr, Eigen::aligned_allocator <pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr >> filtered_clouds2;

//Jede aufgenommene Punktwolke filtern und in vector speichern
for (int i = 0; i < pcl_points1_vector.size(); i++) {

    
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_filtered2(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);

    complete_filter(pcl_points1_vector[i], cloud_filtered);
    complete_filter(pcl_points2_vector[i], cloud_filtered2);

    filtered_clouds1.push_back(cloud_filtered);
    filtered_clouds2.push_back(cloud_filtered2); //After this the error occurs

}
```

complete_filter is made out of 2 filters:

```
void complete_filter(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr& cloud, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr& cloud_filtered) {

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr planes_filtered(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);

remove_planes(cloud, planes_filtered);

downsample_PC(planes_filtered, cloud_filtered);
```

}

```
void downsample_PC(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr& cloud, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr& cloud_filtered) {

    // Downsampling
    cout << "Downsampling each pointcloud... \n";

    pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZRGB> downsample;
    downsample.setInputCloud(cloud);
    downsample.setLeafSize(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f);
    downsample.setFilterFieldName("z");
    downsample.setFilterLimits(0, 1.3); 
    downsample.filter(*cloud_filtered);
    
    }
```

and

```
void filter_radius(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr& cloud, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr& cloud_filtered){
pcl::RadiusOutlierRemoval<pcl::PointXYZRGB> outrem;
outrem.setInputCloud(cloud);
outrem.setRadiusSearch(0.01);
outrem.setMinNeighborsInRadius(13);
outrem.filter(*cloud_filtered);

std::cout << "Cloud size after removing with RadiusOutlierRemoval: " << cloud_filtered->points.size() << std::endl;}
```

If I put the point clouds created outside the for loop the error vanishes but the vector is filled with the same pointer over and over. I have 0 clue on how to tackle this problem and am too inexperienced with C++. Does anyone have a clue how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try to find out where exactly (which line) the debug assertion is thrown?

Comment: I looked more into it, it seems to be at down sample.filter(*cloud_filtered), so at the end of the downsample function which is the last function to be called inside the loop

Comment: Could you say more about your environment? OS? Compiler? Which PCL version and how you installed it?

Comment: I will edit the main post with those infos sorry about that

Comment: This might have something to do with SIMD instructions. Have you tried PCL 1.12.1? Make sure you remove PCL 1.12.0 completely before installing the newer version.

Comment: `std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr, Eigen::aligned_allocator <pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr >>`. The provided allocator seems fishy to me, try it without the allocator, e.g. `std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr>`.

Comment: ALRIGHT, some things I changed: I upgraded to pcl 1.12.1 which didnt change anything, removed the allocator because it doesn't make much difference on the surface (issue is somewhere else) and instead of passing references I copy the pointclouds into the vector which fixed the issue. After the for loop the pointers just point to an invalid address which I guess makes sense since the point clouds are created inside the for. I am sure there is a better solution (and copying is probably the worst case here) but it works for me I guess...

Answer (score 0):

I will just copy paste my own answer in the comments here:

ALRIGHT, some things I changed: I upgraded to pcl 1.12.1 which didnt change anything, removed the allocator because it doesn't make much difference on the surface (issue is somewhere else) and instead of passing references I copy the pointclouds into the vector which fixed the issue. After the for loop the pointers just point to an invalid address which I guess makes sense since the pointclouds are created inside the for. I am sure there is a better solution (and copying is probably the worst case here) but it works for me I guess...